# Xamarin Forms : Awaiting NavigationPage.PushAsync causes application crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I'm facing a weird error. We're building a Xamarin Forms app. We've used MVVM Light framework and use a navigation service for navigating between pages. We've used [Mark's Implementation](https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin.forms-navigation-with-mvvm-light) with a few additions. But primarily we use async functions, so the Navigate function is

```
 public async Task NavigateTo(string pageKey, object parameter)
```

and a few differences

```
Device.OnPlatform(Android: () => NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false));    
await _navigation.PushAsync(page, false);
```

Now this worked fine for like a whole month. Yes we've changed the app a lot since then, but the navigation service itself remained the same. Today out of the blue we start getting this exception ***System.ObjectDisposedExceptionCannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PageContainer'.***

I'm attaching the entire Raw stack trace we got from Insights too.

> System.ObjectDisposedExceptionCannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PageContainer'.
>   Raw
>     at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self) [0x00030] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/5a02b032/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.cs:153 
>     at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/5a02b032/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:21 
>     at Android.Views.View.set_Visibility (Android.Views.ViewStates value) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/5a02b032/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:10321 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.NavigationRenderer.SwitchContentAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page view, System.Boolean animated, System.Boolean removed) [0x002d7] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:319 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.NavigationRenderer.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page view, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:142 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.NavigationRenderer.PushViewAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:36 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.NavigationRenderer.OnPushed (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NavigationRequestedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\NavigationRenderer.cs:175 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__90.MoveNext () [0x0006a] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:355 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage+d__48.MoveNext () [0x0017f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\NavigationPage.cs:180 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
>     at CustomerApp.Infrastructure.NavigationService+d__7.MoveNext () [0x000f1] in C:\SVN Repos\Jam Dev\Trunk\MobileApp\CustomerApp\CustomerApp\CustomerApp\Infrastructure\Navigation\NavigationService.cs:97 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
>     at CustomerApp.Infrastructure.NavigationService+d__6.MoveNext () [0x00030] in C:\SVN Repos\Jam Dev\Trunk\MobileApp\CustomerApp\CustomerApp\CustomerApp\Infrastructure\Navigation\NavigationService.cs:69 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
>     at CustomerApp.ViewModels.Login.LoginViewModel+d__36.MoveNext () [0x0024e] in C:\SVN Repos\Jam Dev\Trunk\MobileApp\CustomerApp\CustomerApp\CustomerApp\ViewModels\Login\LoginViewModel.cs:234

Now the funny thing is while I was trying to debug and see what the problem was I decided to remove the await keyword in front of the pushasync call so now my code looks like

```
Device.OnPlatform(Android: () => NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false));                    
_navigation.PushAsync(page, false);
```

And voila!!! It starts working again. Although I'm glad that it's working, I'm just wondering why it did and what caused it. Am I supposed to use await or am I not supposed to. Could someone please explain?